# Calling WebService From Same Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, server.mappath

I'm trying to call an asp.net webservice from the same project it's in:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static void OnFileCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {

    trackdata_analyse rWebAnalyse = new trackdata_analyse();
    rWebAnalyse.Analyse(@"pending\" + e.Name, "YOUNIVATE");

}
```

However i always get the following "**HttpContext is not available.   This class can only be used in the context of an ASP.NET request.**" when calling Server.MapPath from the webservice:

```
[WebMethod]
public int Analyse(string fileName, string PARSING_MODULE){

    int nRecords;
    TrackSession rTrackSession = new TrackSession() ;
    string filePath = Server.MapPath(@"..\data\") + fileName;
```

Do i have to add the WebReference instead, though the webservice is in the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of depending exclusively on the `HttpContext` in your web service (not generally a good practice), you should add a parameterized constructor to your `WebService` class.  Then, in the default parameterless constructor, you can check the `HttpContext` for the same dependencies.

That way, when you need to invoke the web service from the same assembly, you can share dependencies in-process instead of relying in the `HttpContext`.

In this case your dependency is `Server.MapPath`, which maps a relative path in a URL to a physical path on the hard drive.  You can adjust your web service to accept a specific path or base path instead, and when none is supplied, use `Server.MapPath` to locate it.

Or you can create an interface abstraction, say `IPathMapper`, with one implementation that wraps `Server.MapPath` and another that just wraps a physical path, and use the second one from within the same assembly.

I'd really recommend this over adding a web reference from within your web service assembly; the latter is going to *significantly* hurt performance, not to mention making your service app more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Or I can user HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, plays well to get the base dir

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use the HTTP Context, the call has to come in from the web (via a web reference as you suggest).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do, because the request is going out and back into the solution through the web interface.